# UIImage resizing - how scaleFactor value derived is unclear

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, scale

This is possibly a dumb question, but I'm not seeing how the math works here. I have an image, 414w x 584h. To get an image scaled down to half this size (i.e., half the initial width and height), using `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:scaleFactor:orientation]`, I have to set `scaleFactor` to 6.0.

Why is it 6.0? How does this value relate to say, a width scale of 414/207 = 2.0, or a height scale, same value, 584/292 = 2.0?

As I write this, I'm wondering... my app is running on an iPhone 6+. So could it have something to do with the 3x Retina display? I.e., normal scale factor of 2.0, which is dimensionless, but when applied to images on the 6+, to get to pixels, I have to do 3x this? Is this the logic?

And, I guess, while I'm here, is there a better way to resize an image, using available iOS facilities? E.g., some special affine transform, etc.? No particular concerns around memory or performance; the images are all no more than 1000 wide by 1500 or so high.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a grt tutorial at http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

The Documentation says:

> The scale factor to use when interpreting the image data. Specifying a scale factor of 1.0 results in an image whose size matches the pixel-based dimensions of the image. Applying a different scale factor changes the size of the image as reported by the size property.

For Scale:

> If you load an image from a file whose name includes the @2x modifier,
>   the scale is set to 2.0. You can also specify an explicit scale factor
>   when initializing an image from a Core Graphics image. All other
>   images are assumed to have a scale factor of 1.0.
>
> If you multiply the logical size of the image (stored in the size
>   property) by the value in this property, you get the dimensions of the
>   image in pixels.

For size:

> In iOS 4.0 and later, this value reflects the logical size of the
>   image and is measured in points. In iOS 3.x and earlier, this value
>   always reflects the dimensions of the image measured in pixels

Comment: Perfect! Great write-up indeed. Thank you - appreciate your time.